# SQL Server 2008 - Show All Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a Junior Programmer
But I need help with a query
How do I execute a query showing all tables in a Database ??

Comment: `information_schema.tables`, for all tables with some kind off access privilege.

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It will give you a list of tables except view.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: what is information_schema.tables ? and BASE TABLE ?

Comment: Its a view and you can refer this link for more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full name of a table with the schema and table well formatted usable in a query.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)+'.'+QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```